# Part of text dose not show up on screen. JavaScript beginner

Tags: javascript

Ending screen should show winning player and sign "click to continue" which is doing but only with the click to continue. I just start with javascript and i try to write code as logic as i can.

```
function drawEverything() {

canvasContext.fillStyle = 'black';
canvasContext.fillRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);

if (showWinScreen) {
  canvasContext.fillStyle = 'white';
  if (player1Score >= WINNING_SCORE) {
    canvasContext.fillText("PLAYER 1 WON!", 400, 100);
  } else if (player2Score >= WINNING_SCORE) {
    canvasContext.fillText("PLAYER 2 WON!", 400, 100);
  }

  canvasContext.fillText("PLEASE CLICK TO CONTINUE", 350, 500);
  return;
}
```

Variables from this code below are now changed to the part which is last in sequence of work.

```
function ballReset() {
if (player1Score >= WINNING_SCORE ||
  player2Score >= WINNING_SCORE) {
  player1Score = 0;
  player2Score = 0;
  showWinScreen = true;
}
```

Now they are here on part that is closing screen with information which shows who won but problem is still same :/

```
function mouseClick(evt) {
player1Score = 0;
player2Score = 0;
showWinScreen = false;
```

}

Comment: if you don't see `PLAYER 1 WON` or `PLAYER 2 WON` then clearly neither player's score is >= the winning score. so clearly the problem is with those variables and not this code - you should try basic debugging steps to figure out why the variables are wrong

Comment: On exactly this same variables is another part of code that works fine.
function ballReset() {
    if (player1Score >= WINNING_SCORE ||
      player2Score >= WINNING_SCORE) {
      player1Score = 0;
      player2Score = 0;
      showWinScreen = true;
    }

Answer (score 0):

You only draw the victory message `if (player1Score >= WINNING_SCORE)`. However, `player1Score` gets set to zero in `ballReset()`, so it can't possibly be greater than the `WINNING_SCORE`. You need to store the winning player some other way or don't reset the scores to zero until the game restarts.

Comment: I transfer this variables to ending part but problem is same :/